# Verification of power law

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: QUESTION]

[image]

Here is the solution that I have so far.

How are the values of Vx different if we solve it using KVL and different if we use Ohms Law?

And to verify the power law, do i need to calculate the current through each voltage source?

Answer (score 0):

In your KVL equation for loop 1 you have assumed that the voltage across the dependent current source is zero. That's not a valid assumption. You might want to try KCL instead of KVL.

If by "power law" you mean conservation of power, then you need to determine the current through each voltage source and the voltage across each current source.